# java interface on grails domain class

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I have four components in my large project that I'm working on...

1. Existing JPA/Hibernate java library (java domain).
2. Existing service layer that works with the java domain.
3. Java class library of only basic interfaces (api and meta-data).
4. New grails project

I have successfully tied most of this together except one last piece.  I have an existing servlet that takes in a interface class from the api but I can't seem to implement my interface on any of the grails domain classes.

An example...

Interface example in the api library...

```
public interface IPerson{
    public Object getId()
    public String getName()
}
```

Grails domain class...

```
class Person implements IPerson{
...
    def getId(){
        return id
    }

    String getName(){
       return name;
    }

}
```

My project works fine without the interface on the grails domain class but as soon as I add it, **it seems to not be identified as an entity**.  I get errors like

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static com.some.thing.Person.getAll() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

Has anyone ever tried something like this?

Comment: Do you have also setters (even with empty body) for `id` and `name` in `Person`? I don't know if they are omitted in listing or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is apparently caused by the fact that one of the methods is called `getId()`, so it's  essentially defining domain class field `id`, which clashes with the implicit one. So you can solve the problem by renaming this method or (hopefully, haven't tested myself) changing generation strategy as described [here](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/id.html).

Comment: I played with the Id field a little and I found a workaround without renaming.  Thanks.

Comment: What about using traits ?